# Add new column to the product table

Tags: nopcommerce

Nopcommerce uses binary code to store the images in the database, that's a big 'no no' for me because I want the images in a folder so the supplier can upload/update those via FTP.

Now I added a new column called `imagePath` to the product table, but I cant use it now in my project. I already searched for an ADO entity file but could not find anything.

Does someone know how to do this, or is there a work around for my problem.?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do this as it's already been supported. Just change the settings in nopCommerce Admin Dashboard to store the image in file system. :)

Comment: Not posible because I use images.otherdomain.com.

Answer (score -1):

add new property in Product.cs and ProductModel.cs

```
public string imagePath { get; set; }
```

Add this property in your **Product** table.

**Note**: Manually add this column in table is necessary.

Change your ProductController and its related View. Now you can pass your external imagepath based on your requirement.

If you want to get to more detail about [Add Custom Field In NopCommerce Table](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLlJDc0PfOAhWMrI8KHXLWDf44ChAWCE8wCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fhow-to-add-new-column-in-existing-table-in-nopcommerce&usg=AFQjCNEkDPFiH-otOP_9SaHCp9-UMwsI5w&sig2=j00kZ9povXzPnR5gnDcuMQ&bvm=bv.131783435,d.c2I)

Comment: You should do your research before answering. Because NopCommerce supports file system storage and database image storage. It's just a matter of changing the setting to support file system storage rather than database storage.